# How to add space in a variable

Tags: linux, bash, unix, csh

```
#!/bin/bash
 echo " Please enter 1 or 2 "
read num1
while IFS= read -r line
 do
Temp1=`./fahr_kel $num1    $line`
echo  "      " $Temp1
echo "--------       -------- "
done < "project3.data"
```

I have looked this all over the internet and stack overflow but with no luck of finding a solution, tried the \t and \n, also tried putting the quotation mark around the variable with no luck. I have a C program in Linux that i wrote passing in two arguments, I want to print a space between those two arguments but it looks like it is not working!

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do, could you please add to your post a description of the results you have, and of what you expect your program to do?

Comment: Temp1=`./fahr_kel $num1    $line`     I want to print a space between $num1 and $line !

Comment: Like this : `./script "$num1" "   $line"` ?

Comment: Yup exactly, except it still doesn't work!

Comment: why are you using backquotes after `TEMP1=` ? If you want cmd-substitution, use `TEMP1=$(./fahr_kel $num1 $line)`, If you just want to change the value of TEMP1, then use `TEMP1="./farhr_kel $num1 $line"` . Else please improve your Q with small sample input for `project3.data` file, the expected output, your current output and any errors or warning messages that appear. Good luck.

Comment: you placed a tag of `csh`, though it is a `bash` script. csh doesn't have read in it, so we can't help there. please remove the tag...